# What's the point of having a morgue?

Tags: prison-architect

Whenever a prisoner or staff member is killed, a hearse drives up and immediately takes them away. Knowing that the [morgue](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Morgue) is a source of contraband, what is the purpose of even having one?